# How to connect to on-premise api from Dynamics 365 plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

What is the most performant and secure method to call an on-premise API (integrated to on-premise systems not related to CRM) from a Dynamics 365 plugin in Azure?

Comment: Still missing: what have you tried, where are you stuck, what have you tried to get yourself unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to user Dynamics API when you are already in Plugin for Azure.

Why not user native SDK for Dynamics on-prem .net4.6.2
Connect to Dynamics in Plugin using connection tool and use it.

Here is an example to do so, once connected you can perform CURD operation against dynamics.

https://crm365blog.wordpress.com/2018/05/27/connecting-to-crm-2013-2015-2016-and-dynamics-365-in-c/

one more article

https://rawishblog.wordpress.com/2018/07/16/how-to-connect-to-dynamics-crm-onpremises-ad-ifd-from-a-windows-form-application/

Comment: The on-premise api is not CRM related. I have updated the question to be clearer. Thanks